# ulimit for virtual memory size of a process

Tags: linux, bash, out-of-memory, heap-memory, ulimit

I'm running Linux OS (Ubuntu) on virtual box. When I am running the command

```
ulimit -Sv 50
```

It's not setting the soft limit for virtual memory size in that bash session. The error I'm getting is:

```
fatal error: out of heap memory
```

I was running above command with sudo access. The output of ulimit -a is as follow:

```
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       515266
-n: file descriptors                1024
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  64
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 515266
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        0
-r: max rt priority                 0
-N 15:                              unlimited
```

I ran a binary with AFL using memory size (-m) = 50 MB. So, I need to run this binary (without AFL) with the same memory size. Any insights will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are setting limit to 50 **kilo**bytes and not 50 megabytes (see units in `help ulimit`).